# App deployed on IIS not connecting to local db

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis

ASP.NET Core 3.1 app deployed on IIS not connecting to local db but its connecting to something. The app is working `Application 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\retailbanking\' started successfully.` on windows logs. I have a bunch of users registered in `dbo.aspnetusers` but when I launch the website from IIS none of the users I try to login with are registered. I am also able to recreate these users but I have no idea where they are being stored in since my db I'm using is not being populated. My `appsettings.json` is correct since everything works when I run it but when deploying it, it doesnt seems to connect correctly.

#### appsetting.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default Connection": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=Retail Banking;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}
```

#### applicationHost.config

```
<applicationPoolDefaults managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0">
    <processModel identityType="ApplicationPoolIdentity" loadUserProfile="true" setProfileEnvironment="true" />
</applicationPoolDefaults>
```

[image]

I've tried both local system and applicationpoolidentity.

[image]

Comment: local db only makes sense during development, and the web server not likely to have localdb support anyway. Get a instance of SQL server express installed and running on that server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use localdb when hosting in IIS. LocalDB is launched in the context of the user running it. On you dev box, that going to be YOU the "super user" with all rights etc.

LocalDB databases are owned and accessible by the user who creates it.

In IIS you don't have a Profile by default. While there are workarounds, they are all more or less dirty and not an option.

LocalDB is launched in the context of the user running it - and that's not really a practical for a working web site.

(LocalDB databases owned and accessed by the user who creates it (that would be you on your development computer - again the "super" admin of your computer))

In IIS you don't have a Profile by default. Messy workarounds are possible.

Install either SQL Server Express or the full version of SQL Server.

LocalDB is ONLY for easy development without requiring to install SQL Server Express or SQL Server full version.

For all practical purposes you want to have a running instance of SQL server.

Comment: thanks looks like using sql server express was a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

By default LocalDb instances are not shared between users.
So either run the app as yourself, or move the database to a [shared instance of LocalDb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver16#shared-instances-of-localdb) instance, or a Service-based install of [SQL Server Express Edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads).

Comment: i ran `sqllocaldb share MSSQLLocalDB MSSQLLocalDB_shared` on cmd and then on my appsettings.json i updated the connection string to use the shared instance `"ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default Connection": "Data Source=(localdb)\\.\\MSSQLLocalDB_shared;Initial Catalog='Retail Banking';Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
  }` i then restarted the app pool but still it doesnt seem to connect to this one too. am i doing the shared instance correctly?

Comment: Looks like you have too many backslashes in the connection string.  The example in the docs is `(localdb)\.\AppData`

Comment: hmm i did try `Data Source=(localdb)\.\MSSQLLocalDB_shared;` but would get `invalid escape sequence` so i tried using `@` infront of the string and it auto formatted to `"@\"Data Source=(localdb)\\.\\MSSQLLocalDB_shared;Initial Catalog='Retail Banking';Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False\""` but this broke the app so changing to just `Data Source=(localdb)\\.\\MSSQLLocalDB_shared;`

Comment: Of course.  That's JSON which _also_ uses backslash as the escape character.